# How to create a custom app entry inside the Application Settings with Windows Phone SDK

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

Do you know if the *Windows Phone SDK* offers an API that allows to add a custom App entry inside the Application Settings page?

[image]

I would like to create a new entry "AppXYZ" that links the settings page of the application.
Is this view reserved just for "system" applications or could also be used to add a link to an external app's settings?

Answer (score 4):

Although not well-known, there is a way to do that. In `WMAppManifest.xml` you can specify that your app belongs in `HubType="268435456"`. That way, it will be integrated there. This is not an officially-supported approach and I am yet to see a third-party app approved in the Store that would handle this.

Comment: It does. I've tested it.

Comment: Really? I've added a new `HubType` attribute inside the `<app` node without success. I will give it another chance.

Answer (score -1):

You can link to the settings page of your own application but not to the windows phone settings page you show us in the screenshot. Developers are only allowed to show some of these by using the corresponding URL schmemes.

Unfortuantely there is no possibility to integrate your app to the official settings hub as a third party developer. Adding `HubType="268435456"` in your WMAppManifest.xml file will prevent a successful sumbission.

Sorry for the bad news...

Comment: Actually I would like to add a link inside the settings page in the screenshot that points to the setting of the app I'm developing.

Comment: Ah okay. That is not possible unfortunately. I corrected the answer.